# How to resolve following error while exporting APK in release mode?

Tags: android, android-proguard

```
    :app:proguardDebug
Warning:com.google.common.base.Absent: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable

Warning:com.google.common.collect.Collections2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable

Warning:com.google.common.collect.Tables$UnmodifiableTable: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeBasedTable$TreeRow: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeMultimap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset$Aggregate: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset$Aggregate$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset$Aggregate$2: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset$AvlNode: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset$Reference: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeMap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeMap$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeMap$AsMapOfRanges: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeMap$SubRangeMap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeMap$SubRangeMap$SubRangeMapAsMap$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeSet: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeSet$AsRanges: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeSet$ComplementRangesByLowerBound: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeSet$RangesByUpperBound: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeSet$SubRangeSet: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.TreeRangeSet$SubRangeSetRangesByLowerBound: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.collect.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:com.google.common.escape.ArrayBasedUnicodeEscaper: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.escape.Escapers$Builder: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.escape.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:com.google.common.eventbus.AnnotatedSubscriberFinder$MethodIdentifier: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.hash.BloomFilter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.hash.Funnels$SequentialFunnel: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.hash.Funnels$StringCharsetFunnel: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.hash.HashCode: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.hash.Hashing$ConcatenatedHashFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.hash.Murmur3_128HashFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.hash.Murmur3_32HashFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.hash.SipHashFunction: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.hash.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:com.google.common.html.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:com.google.common.io.AppendableWriter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding$StandardBaseEncoding: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.CharSource: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.Closeables: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.Closer: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.CountingInputStream: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.CountingOutputStream: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.MultiInputStream: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.MultiReader: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.PatternFilenameFilter: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.io.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:com.google.common.math.MathPreconditions: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.math.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:com.google.common.net.HostAndPort: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.net.HostAndPort: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.Immutable
Warning:com.google.common.net.HostSpecifier: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.net.InetAddresses$TeredoInfo: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.net.MediaType: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.net.MediaType: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.concurrent.Immutable
Warning:com.google.common.net.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.Doubles: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.Floats: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.Ints: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckForNull
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedInteger: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedLong: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.primitives.package-info: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
Warning:com.google.common.reflect.AbstractInvocationHandler: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.reflect.ClassPath$Scanner: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.reflect.Element: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.reflect.Invokable: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.reflect.Invokable$ConstructorInvokable: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.reflect.Invokable$MethodInvokable: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable
Warning:com.google.common.reflect.MutableTypeToInstanceMap: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nullable

Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class 
Warning:there were 1326 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
:app:proguardDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:proguardDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 8.387 secs
Information:1 error
Information:536 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Comment: It seems your are using proguard and not edit properties of proguard properly.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Disable the warnings in your proguard config-

```
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
```

The same for other warnings.

Comment: Why are we disabling these warnings? can't we use keep class or something else? I am also stuck in this

Answer (score 0):

If you are pretty confident about your dependencies
You can also use:

```
-ignorewarnings
```

[This proguard option](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#ignorewarnings) will take care of all potential warnings simply by ignoring them.